# How do I filter a dataframe column using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is my regex
`date_regex='\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$'`

[image: dates_as_first_row Dataframe]

Here is my dates_as_first_row Dataframe

I am trying to filter out the date column but get an empty (377,0) Dataframe.
`date_column=dates_as_first_row.filter(regex=attempt,axis='columns')`

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do, do you want all the rows which have a date in column 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `.str.match`.

If your column is named `'0'`, it looks like this:

```
indexer=df['0'].str.match('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$')
df[indexer]
```

If you want to select all rows which contain the pattern in any of the string columns, you can do:

```
#          v- select takes all object columns     
#                             v- apply the lambda expression to each of the selected object columns with True if the row contains the pattern in the specific column
#                                                                                                        v- if any of the column vectors contains True, return True, otherwise False (the column vectors contain the result of str.match which is a boolean)
indexer=df.select_dtypes('O').apply(lambda ser: ser.str.match('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$'), axis='index').any(axis='columns')
df[indexer]
```

But note, that this only works, if all your `object` columns actually store strings. Which is usually the case if you let pandas figure out the types of the columns itself when the dataframe is created. If that is not the case, you need to add a type check, to avoid a runtime error:

```
import re

def filter_dates(ser):
    date_re= re.compile('\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$')
    return ser.map(lambda val: type(val) == str and bool(date_re.match(val)))

df.select_dtypes('O').apply(filter_dates, axis='index').any(axis='columns')
```

Comment: What if I don't know the column number?

Comment: How would you like to filter, if you don't even know the name of the column? Would you like to output all lines which have a date in some of the columns? that would be possible as well, by just filtering for string columns. But I would recommend to assingn names to the columns, because you probably need to do other stuff that would be much easier like that